# Finding localhost/phpmyadmin ip-address

Tags: phpmyadmin, ip, arduino

I am trying to connect my arduino to phpmyadmin so I can save data in the database. The problem have been finding the ipaddress for the phpmyadmin.

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Is it going into byte server here: http://ambrosedigiorgio.com/tutorials/garage_door/garage_door.ino

Comment: You may mean MySQL (or MariaDB) where you wrote phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is an application for administrators to manage a database; the other two are actual database engines. I'm not sure that you really want to access phpMyAdmin from your Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the host address, there are exemple of how to use DNS.

But that is a really bad idea, probably won't work because arduino does not support HTTPS (SSL/TSL) because it has not enought resource, and leaving full DB access unprotected is really a bad idea.
You can still create a php "bridge" page, you call it by arduino wiath a get/post request, and the page will take care of filtering and putting data into database.

Maybe someone will fill your table with data, but at least won't drop all your tables..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your database server isn't running on your Arduino machine, so just find the IP address of that server. There are a host of different ways to do so; probably the easiest is to log in to the shell on that machine as root and type `ifconfig`. That will display a whole bunch of networking information, but the interesting part for you will be on the second line beginning with "inet addr:" followed by your IP address. If you have more than one network interface configured, you'll see them all listed.

Note that to connect to the database server from another computer, it has to allow remote connections and the user you're connecting as also has to have an appropriate value in the 'host' field of the mysql users table (such as `%` or `192.168.1.15`; this host field is also displayed in phpMyAdmin in the Users tab).